# on multi-threaded program printf on console and redirection to file have different order

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, pthreads, stdout

I'm writing a program that displaying The Dining Philosophers with timestamp. Each number means thread that I created.

This is part of my code:

```
i = -1;
while (++i < num_philos)
{   
    error = pthread_create(&philos[i].tid, NULL, dining, &philos[i]);
    if (error)
        return (release_rscs(init_val.forks, init_val.start, init_val.last_meals));
}

i = -1;
while (++i < num_philos)
    pthread_detach(philos[i].tid);
```

When I print on console as usual, its order is messed up like:

```
...
[1ms] 42 is eating
[0ms] 18 take right fork
[1ms] 18 is eating
[0ms] 26 take left fork
[1ms] 26 take right fork
...
```

But when I redirect output to file, the order is more like what I expected:

```
...
[1ms] 172 is eating
[1ms] 174 take left fork
[1ms] 174 take right fork
[1ms] 174 is eating
[2ms] 176 take left fork
[2ms] 176 take right fork
[2ms] 176 is eating
...
```

Not only is the order different, but performance is also improved.
Why they are different? Is it thread related or just buffer related?

Comment: When writing to console, the output stream is probably line-buffered (output is flushed at end of every line), whereas when writing to file, it is probably fully buffered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple threads are running, the order in which in-program functions get executed (relative to each other) becomes very difficult to predict, since it depends on the OS's scheduler, the number of cores available for use at any particular instant, what other tasks might be running at the same time, the length of each thread's quantum, the phase of the moon, etc etc etc.  Therefore it's very hard to give any general rules about why things get printed in a certain order; you might be able to dive in and analyze a particular system (hardware, OS, compiler version, etc) and figure it out, but anything you discovered would likely not generalize to other systems, so it's hardly worth the effort.

As for performance of console vs file, consider that "printing" something to a console window requires interacting with the window manager process, rendering a large number of pixels, (often) scrolling pixels upwards inside the Terminal window, etc.  That's a fair amount of work compared to simply writing the output data into a buffer in the system's RAM (which, due to filesystem-caching, is usually what "writing to a file" actually consists of as far as user-visible performance is concerned... the actual sending of the data to disk often happens much later on, often well after the program has completed).  Windows' DOS prompt seems particularly slow in this regard (I suspect that its internal workings are sub-optimal for historical/backwards-compatibility reasons).  It's this difference in overhead (as well as the differing nature of the interfaces your program is interacting with behind the scenes) that likely explains the differing behavior.